# I added UIButtons to my app and made custom images for them, but when I run the app in the simulator, my buttons are severely stretched

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton

This is what the storyboard looks like in Xcode

[image: Screenshot of storyboard in Xcode]

This is what it looks like in the simulator

[image: Screenshot of iOS Simulator]

Does anyone have any idea why this may be happening?

Comment: You should post some code or more info if you'd like to get some help.

Comment: Are you sure you are not messing with these buttons in code?

Comment: I have not coded anything yet. I've only dragged the buttons in and chosen "Custom" and chose the button image in the right Attributes Inspector. This is a screenshot of my buttons with the settings in the Attributes Inspector: [Screenshot](http://imgur.com/h2hvZ8D).

Edit: The only code I've added is `@property` codes for each button in MainViewController.h and `@synthesize`d them in MainViewController.m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the autolayout constraints for each button are setup properly. i.e. your top left button should probably have a constraint for its width and height and should pin its leading and top space to its superview.

[image: Contraints]

Comment: The settings you suggest appear to be set correctly. [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/xARsqIe.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try resizing your images to the frame size of your UIButton and generate an @2x copy for your retina display. You can also try setting the mode to aspect fit in the attribute inspector.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the buttons and re-added them, and now it's working well. Thanks for the insights.